# JavaScript and CSS - places random dots on the screen too slow

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I have a simple script that places random dots on the screen.
Using Javascript and CSS

```
<!doctype html><html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ran Dots</title>

<style>
    body{
    background-color:#C82022;
    }
    .dot {
        position: absolute;
        width: 2px;
        height: 2px;
        background: black;
    }
</style>

</head><body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="textfield">num of dots</label>
  <input type="text" id="num_of_dots" value="0" />
</form>

<script>
//
function createDot(x, y){
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.setAttribute("class", "dot");
    elem.setAttribute("style", "left:"+x+"px;top:"+y+"px;");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(elem);
    return elem;
}
//

var Count_Num_Of_Dots = 0;
//
function Add_Dot(){

        if(Count_Num_Of_Dots < 1000000){

            createDot(Math.floor(Math.random()*1900), Math.floor(Math.random()*870 + 40));
            Count_Num_Of_Dots ++;
            document.getElementById('num_of_dots').value ++;

        }else{// stop timer

            clearInterval(My_Timer_Var);

        }
}
//

// Timer
var My_Timer_Var = setInterval(function(){ Add_Dot() }, .05);
</script>

</body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me:

- what inevitably causes it to slow down at around 30,000 dots?
- how can I keep these dots going efficiently and with good speed into the millions of dots?
- Maybe there is a better way to do this?

JSFiddle : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UpxzB/)

Thank you

Regards.

Comment: The second paramer of `setTimeout` is measured in **millsecond**. If you mean 0.5 second, you should use `500` instead.

Comment: So... What are you aiming to do here? Create slow-mo static?

Comment: Try to put 1000 dots in millisecond http://jsfiddle.net/UpxzB/1/

Comment: Interesting idea @inon ... Thanks
Still slows down though eh? Anyone know what is actually causing it to slow down?

Comment: Hi @JAL "Aiming to achieve over 1million dots with a smooth and steady pace that does not bog sown. Thanks

Comment: Okay, a million dot march. Alright

Comment: @JAL: haha, no *million**s***..  (so millions of dom-nodes containing (on average) `<div style="left: ???px; top: ???px;" class="dot">`, so > 4.7MB per million, just for the innerHTML. This thing will eventually bring down ANY browser on ANY platform... Hence the advise to use the proper thing: CANVAS.

Comment: The DOM is an overkill for this, 1m dots with result in 1.5GB memory allocation from chrome. useless. Use canvas.

Comment: Good point @GitaarLAB .. Makes some sense. So - really we are talking about processing power then? Of the browser / Computer?

Comment: Yep, both: the browser and the computer: The browser asks processing power for the css (besides your functions) and needs memory (provided by the host-machine). Something must fail eventually..

Comment: I appreciate the advice to use "canvas" can someone point me in the right direction for that and perhaps explain how this "canvas" will differ?

Comment: Canvas will not store a whole fat DOM object for every dot - just the pixel level info.

Comment: Basically canvas is a bitmap, an image... So, you dynamically change the image, not overload the DOM. Do some googling on canvas, there is loads of examples. Ask when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Aron Zentai ... can someone please point me in the right direction to start with this script on "canvas"

Comment: besides batching of dots will be needed there too. the one dot/callback  will not be a good practise even with canvas

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial

Comment: Anyone care to formulate an answer that explains the DOM memory consumption for this and why it is actually slowing down - I would be happy to check as answer
Regards All : ) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good point @Peter Aron Zentai - I was thinking of some kind of solution like that with javascript... Maybe if there was a way to batch 10000 dots as one DOM object? I dunno ... just looking for the reason why and a solution : )

Comment: as for the why: DOM objects with those dynamically applied css capabilities are just too powerful => requires too much resource from your browser/computer. Consider: after you create (if you are able) 1 million dots with DIVS: you would be capable to intercept every DOM event per dot, or change their background color by simply changing some values in the CSS. This level of dynamic behavior means a hell of a number of event handlers, ptrs, handles etc in the background.

Comment: **Q**: "Maybe if there was a way to batch 10000 dots as one DOM object?" **A**: Every element (inside your 'wrapper' element) is a DOM object (and all of them (childNodes) get cloned (or there would be no result)). Period.

Comment: A DOM object is an expensive/intensive thing for a browser to create. Browsers are created to render documents: documents do not typically have over 30,000 nodes, much less a million.

Answer (score 1):

it is not an answer just a skeleton to start with canvas, rather then DOM.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
      }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat..: why did you use "application/javascript"? I thought that "text/javascript" is the only type that is supported by all browsers (although, you might not want to use a polyfill to support older IE versions in this case).

Comment: important: please try avoiding calling canvas.getContext 1 million times. cache the pointer to some variable.